# Is there a way to generate multiple addresses at once?

Tags: myetherwallet

I can use MyEtherWallet to generate a new Ethereum address. But using it I generate one address at a time. This takes a long time to generate, let's say, 100 private keys.

Is there a way to automate this process?

For example, I click one button and 100 (or any number) Ethereum private keys are generated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about programmatically, yes of course! Ethereum web3js allows you to generate public addresses with a private key generated programatically. Calling that function allows you to generate as many keypairs as you wish in short amount of time dependant on performance.

Answer (score 0):

Get [web3](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API)

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3('ws://localhost:8546');
var accounts = web3.eth.accounts;

var keys = [];
var amount = 10;

for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    keys.push(accounts.create(web3.utils.randomHex(32)));
}
```

This should in theory do it.

[Docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html)